# SQL Server INSTEAD of INSERT trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a requirement of writing a SQL Server trigger which populates some of the columns of particular table.

For example, I have table called 'mytable' and columns

```
"ID", "NAME", "ADDRESS", "AGE", "CREATED_AT", "CREATED_BY", "MODIFIED_AT", "MODIFIED_BY"
```

Now I am populating all the columns through application except these 2 columns

```
"CREATED_AT", "CREATED_BY"
```

I would like to create a trigger which populates these 2 columns with following values when application commits record in database.

- `CREATED_AT` - Database time-stamp UTC
- `CREATED_BY` - Database User Id

I heard that SQL Server does not have `BEFORE INSERT` triggers.

Can someone help me on how to write this trigger ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use a `TIMESTAMP` type that will by default add the current date+time to the value.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - Can you please help me with the syntax of trigger

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - I'd be careful talking about `timestamp` since in SQL Server, that type has nothing to do with wall-clock time.

Comment: @DeepInJava: but that is not a trigger: it is a special type that always uses the current time as default value.

Comment: For this particular task you don't need trigger at all. You can just set `getutcdate()` and `system_user` functions as default values for you columns

Comment: What do you have so far for your trigger INSERT statement? Are you able to alter the CREATED_AT column to have a DEFAULT value?

Comment: @DeepInJava - are you sure that this table structure will actually meet your needs? The sequence `sane insert by user 1, insane update by user 2, sane update by user 3` will end up only identifying users 1 & 3. Are you sure you don't need an actual audit?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I just gave dummy table for example. audit columns not gonna update by application.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev - I know we don't need trigger at all. but due to some business requirement I need to do so.

Comment: My point was that people frequently implement this sort of "audit" without considering that it only identifies the first and last users to access this record, and not any of the intermediate updates. You also can't divine *what* was updated by the `modified_by` user.

Comment: Time to let your business know that this is not the way to properly design a database and that you need to use the column defaults properly.

Comment: Why are you insisting on doing this in a trigger which is much, much slower that a default value. Andy Korneyev should get credited with the correct answer.